# MVC 5 - Populate a Html.DropDownList using SQL Connection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, ado.net, html.dropdownlistfor, dropdownlistfor

I'm working on a MVC 5 project and I need to populate a drop down list.
A stored procedure is executed and names are added to a list, I need to present the names in the list in a Html.DropDownList but I haven't have any success. 
I'm using traditional SQL Connection to the database. (SqlConnection, SqlCommand, SqlDataReader)

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/binding-dropdownlist-in-mvc-in-various-ways-in-mvc-with-data/

Above link has some examples on binding dropdownlist in asp.net mvc hope it helps you.